# How to update iPhone OS to the specific iOS 14 beta version?

Tags: ios, beta, ios14

I have the iPhone 11 device which having the iOS 13.6 installed on it.
I want to update it to the iOS 14 with beta 4, not with the latest version.

Currently, when I try to update to iOS 14 its gives option for beta 7 and not for the previous beta versions.

Is there any way to update iPhone to the iOS 14 beta 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **NO official** way to do this.
The purpose of the beta is to test our apps on the version closest to release and let Apple know about problems.
They are not interested in problems on an older beta which may well be corrected in the more recent.

Apple Developer forum link - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/659273